# Delete an attribute line if value is not either TRUE or FALSE

Tags: regex, sed

My input text has attribute-value pairs. I want to delete lines that do not have the values TRUE or FALSE.

```
hasmailbox: TRUE  
hasmailbox: FALSE  
hasmailbox: SS1234  
hasmailbox: me_c1@mybox  
hasmailbox: 04
```

I can easily nuke the line with only digits in it with:

```
/^hasmailbox:.[0-9]\+/d
```

Capture groups seem a step in the right direction but they don't work the way I specified them:

```
/^hasmailbox: (TRUE|FALSE)$/!d
```

But I want a more complete solution that deletes only the lines with this specific attribute name which do not have the values of only 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.

Comment: Do you mean `sed -E "/^hasmailbox: (TRUE|FALSE)$/!d" file`

Comment: The problem is that this also deletes lines that don't begin with `hasmailbox:`

Comment: If your files can have other attributes than `hasmailbox` please edit your question and provide an example with other attributes.

Comment: The title of your question plus this sentence: _I want to delete lines that do not have the values TRUE or FALSE_ contradict this other sentence: _But I want a more complete solution that deletes only the lines with this specific attribute name which do not have the values of only 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'_. Please edit your question and clarify: do you want to delete all lines with any attribute and a value different from `TRUE` or `FALSE`? Or do you want to delete all lines with attribute `hasmailbox` and a value different from `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple print operations, rather than deleting. One prints any lines that don't begin with `hasmailbox:`. The second prints any lines that begin with `hasmailbox:` and end with `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
sed -n -E -e '/^hasmailbox:/!p' -e '/^hasmailbox: (TRUE|FALSE)$/p'
```

Comment: Yes I get your comment now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu-sed` you may do this:

```bash
cat file

hasmailbox: TRUE
hasmailbox: FALSE
hasmailbox: SS1234
hasmailbox: me_c1@mybox
hasmailbox: 04
abc: TRUE
pqrs: foo
xyz: FALSE

# run this gnu sed
sed -E '/^hasmailbox:/!b; /: (TRUE|FALSE)$/!d' file

hasmailbox: TRUE
hasmailbox: FALSE
abc: TRUE
pqrs: foo
xyz: FALSE
```

This `sed` has 2 sub-commands:

- `/^hasmailbox:/!b`: If line doesn't start with text `hasmailbox:` then skip this line
- `/: (TRUE|FALSE)$/!d`: When line doesn't end with `TRUE` or `FALSE` after `:`  then delete that line

---

Here is an equivalent `awk` command to achieve the same that is easier to understand:

```bash
awk -F ': ' '$1 != "hasmailbox" || $2 ~ /(TRUE|FALSE)$/' file

hasmailbox: TRUE
hasmailbox: FALSE
abc: TRUE
pqrs: foo
xyz: FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `gnu-grep` matching either what you want to keep, or match the line that does not start with "hasmailbox:"

```
grep -P "^hasmailbox: (TRUE|FALSE)$|^(?!hasmailbox:)" file
```

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^hasmailbox:/!p' -e '/:[[:space:]]*TRUE[[:space:]]*$/p' -e '/:[[:space:]]*FALSE[[:space:]]*$/p' file
```

With a `sed` that supports `|` (alternation):

```
sed -n -e '/^hasmailbox:/!p' -e '/:[[:space:]]*\(TRUE\|FALSE\)[[:space:]]*$/p' file
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nE '/^hasmailbox:/!p;/:\s*(TRUE|FALSE)\s*$/p' file
```

With any POSIX `awk`:

```
awk '$1!="hasmailbox:" || $NF~/TRUE|FALSE/' file
```

With plain `bash` (not recommended if your file is large):

```
while read -r s; do
  ! [[ "$s" =~ ^hasmailbox: ]] || [[ "$s" =~ :[[:space:]]*(TRUE|FALSE)$ ]] && printf '%s\n' "$s"
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^hasmailbox:\s+(TRUE|FALSE)\s*$/p;/^hasmailbox:/d' file
```

If a line starts with `hasmailbox:`, followed by one or spaces/tabs, followed by either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, followed by zero or more spaces/tabs, followed by the end of line then print it. Then delete any line starting with `hasmailbox:`.